# Get data from 2 tables with a foreign key using Laravel model relationships

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have 2 tables 1) users 2) user_companies.
A user belongs to or has one company,
A company has many users.
This is how I determined my relationships.
How can I pull company data for each user?
Attempt to read property "company" on string - is the error I am receiving with my setup.

Here is what I have tried so far and many other combinations but cant seem to figure out how to show the company name which is stored in the user_companies table under the company column. Not sure what I am missing here.

user model

```
    // Relationship between User and Company
    public function company()
    {       
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'id','company_id');
        //return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }
```

company model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

userController

```
    public function profile(User $user, Company $company)
    {
        $company = Users::with(['company']);
        //$company = Company::with('user')->find('33');
        
        return view('admin.users.profile', compact('user', 'company'));
    }
```

blade file

```
{{ $user->company->company }}
```

migration file (just added new column FK)

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('user_companies')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following.

user model

```
public function company() :BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'user_companies');
}
```

user controller

```
 public function profile(User $user, Company $company)
{
  
    $company = Company::where('id', $user->company)->first();
    return view('admin.users.profile', compact('user', 'company'));
}
```

profile blade file

```
{{ $company->name  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change the relationship of user to company to `belongsTo` :

```
// User.php
public function company() :BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company:;class, 'company_id');
}
```

then eager load it by using `with()`

```
User::with('company')->get();
```

Comment: I get the same error "Attempt to read property "company" on string"
Correct me if im wrong but doesn't get() get you a collection? In my case I am trying to showing the company of one user. The blade file is a profile view. In this case it would be a single id. I can already show data for anything $user->example.

Comment: Does the company has a separate column from the user_companies?

Comment: user_companies is its own table with a column "company"
users is its own table with a column "company_id" foreign key linked to user_companies "id" column